# indexing and finding values in list of namedtuples

Tags: python, namedtuple

I have a namedtuple like the following,

```
tup = myTuple  (
                a=...,
                b=...,
                c=...,
                )
```

where ... could be any value(string, number, date, time, etc). Now, i make a list of these namedtuples and want to find, lets say c=1 and the corresponding value of a and b. Is there any pythonic way of doing this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use List Comprehension, like a filter, like this

```
[[record.a, record.b] for record in records if record.c == 1]
```

For example,

```
>>> myTuple = namedtuple("Test", ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
>>> records = [myTuple(3, 2, 1, 4), myTuple(5, 6, 7, 8)]
>>> [[record.a, record.b] for record in records if record.c == 1]
[[3, 2]]
```